# What is the fastest way to clone an INNODB table within the same server?

Tags: mysql, backup

Our development server is a replication slave of our production server. We have a script that developers use if they want to run their applications/bug fixes against fresh data. That script looks like this:

```
dbs=( analytics auth logs users )
server=localhost
conn="-h ${server} -u ${username} --password=${password}"

# Stop the replication client so we don't encounter weird data.
echo "STOP SLAVE" | mysql ${conn}

# Bunch of bulk insert optimizations
echo "SET autocommit=0" | mysql ${conn}
echo "SET unique_checks=0" | mysql ${conn}
echo "SET foreign_key_checks=0" | mysql ${conn}

# Restore all databases and tables.
for sourcedb in ${dbs[*]}
do
    destdb=${prefix}${sourcedb}
    echo "Dropping database ${destdb}..."
    echo "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${destdb}" | mysql ${conn}
    echo "CREATE DATABASE ${destdb}" | mysql ${conn}

    # First, all the tables.
    for table in `echo "SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type <> 'VIEW'" | mysql $conn $sourcedb | tail -n +2`;
    do
        if [[ "${table}" != 'BASE' && "${table}" != 'TABLE' && "${table}" != 'VIEW' ]] ; then
            createTable=`echo "SHOW CREATE TABLE ${table}"|mysql -B -r $conn $sourcedb|tail -n +2|cut -f 2-`

            echo "Restoring ${destdb}/${table}..."
            echo "$createTable ;" | mysql $conn $destdb

            insertData="INSERT INTO ${destdb}.${table} SELECT * FROM ${sourcedb}.${table}"
                echo "$insertData" | mysql $conn $destdb
            fi
        fi
    done
done

echo "SET foreign_key_checks=1" | mysql ${conn}
echo "SET unique_checks=1" | mysql ${conn}
echo "COMMIT" | mysql ${conn}

# Restart the replication client
echo "START SLAVE" | mysql ${conn}
```

All of these operations are, as I mentioned, within the same server. Is there a faster way to clone the tables I'm not seeing? They're all INNODB tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script

```
echo "SET autocommit=0" | mysql ${conn}
echo "SET unique_checks=0" | mysql ${conn}
echo "SET foreign_key_checks=0" | mysql ${conn}
```

Each time a command is executed, it is immediately undone because the DB connection terminates. Had you placed all you commands in a single file and executed the single file, all the options you are disabling would stay off through the session.

I rewrote the script to put all the commands into a single file, just like a mysqldump would have. I also changed the way the tables are written out as commands. Then, I would run the single file:

```
dbs=( analytics auth logs users )
server=localhost
conn="-h ${server} -u ${username} --password=${password}"

PREFIX=whatever
DUMPFILE=MySQLDataToClone.sql
echo "STOP SLAVE;" > ${DUMPFILE}
echo "SET autocommit=0;" >> ${DUMPFILE}
echo "SET unique_checks=0;" >> ${DUMPFILE}
echo "SET foreign_key_checks=0;" >> ${DUMPFILE}

for SRCDB in ${dbs[*]}
do
    echo "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${PREFIX}${SRCDB};" >> ${DUMPFILE}
    echo "CREATE DATABASE ${PREFIX}${SRCDB};" >> ${DUMPFILE}
done

for SRCDB in ${dbs[*]}
do
    SQLTOGETTABLES="SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ${PREFIX}',dbtb,' LIKE ',dbtb,'; INSERT INTO ${PREFIX}',dbtb,' SELECT * FROM dbtb;') FROM (SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name) dbtb FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='${SRCDB}' AND engine IS NOT NULL) A;"
    mysql $conn -ANe"${SQLTOGETTABLES}" >> ${DUMPFILE}
done

echo "START SLAVE;" >> ${DUMPFILE}

mysql ${conn} < ${DUMPFILE}
```

Give it a Try !!!